# Working on 64-point SDF FFT Verilog code

Tags: verilog, fft

I am an undergraduate student who has chosen to work on an FPGA project for my capstone. My professor provided me with a PDF file without any context, and now I am trying to figure it out on my own. I have a Verilog code for a "64-point SDF FFT," and my task is to complete the code for the final stage. However, I'm currently at a loss and could use some guidance.

I have a basic understanding of the concept, but I'm still exploring and learning about it.

```
/Stage 1 to 5
module Stage(nrst,clk,bf_en,cnt,inReal,inImag, valid, outReal,outImag);
parameter BW=16;
parameter N =32;

input           nrst,clk,bf_en;
input [BW-2:0]  inReal,inImag;
input [5:0]     cnt;
input           valid;
output[BW-1:0]  outReal,outImag;

reg  [BW-2:0] rReal,rImag;

wire [BW-1:0] bf_x[1:0];
wire [BW-1:0] bf_y[1:0];

wire [BW-1:0] mult_out[1:0];

wire [BW-1:0] sr_out[1:0];

wire [BW-1:0] mux0[1:0];
wire [BW-1:0] mux1[1:0];


assign mux0[0] = bf_en? bf_x[0] : sr_out[0];
assign mux0[1] = bf_en? bf_x[1] : sr_out[1];

assign mux1[0] = bf_en? bf_y[0] : {rReal[BW-2],rReal};
assign mux1[1] = bf_en? bf_y[1] : {rImag[BW-2],rImag};

Shift_Reg #(BW,N) sr0(nrst,clk,mux1[0],valid,sr_out[0]);
Shift_Reg #(BW,N) sr1(nrst,clk,mux1[1],valid,sr_out[1]);

BF #(BW)bf0({sr_out[0][BW-1],sr_out[0][BW-3:0]},{sr_out[1][BW-1],sr_out[1][BW-3:0]},rReal,rImag,bf_x[0],bf_x[1],bf_y[0],bf_y[1]);

MULT #(.BW(BW),.N(N))mult0(mux0[0],mux0[1],cnt[4:0],mult_out[0],mult_out[1]);

assign outReal = bf_en? mux0[0] : mult_out[0];
assign outImag = bf_en? mux0[1] : mult_out[1];


always@(posedge clk) begin
    if(!nrst) begin
      rReal <= 0;
      rImag <= 0;
    end
    else if(valid) begin
        
      rReal <= inReal;
      rImag <= inImag;

    end
end

endmodule

/Stage 6
module Stage6(nrst,clk,bf_en,inReal,inImag,valid,outReal,outImag);
parameter BW=16;
parameter N =1;

input           nrst,clk,bf_en;
input [BW-2:0]  inReal,inImag;
input           valid;
output[BW-1:0]  outReal,outImag;

reg   [BW-2:0]  rReal,rImag;

wire  [BW-1:0]  bf_x[1:0];
wire  [BW-1:0]  bf_y[1:0];

reg   [BW-1:0]  sr_out[1:0];

wire  [BW-1:0]  mux0[1:0];
wire  [BW-1:0]  mux1[1:0];

assign mux0[0] = bf_en? bf_x[0] : sr_out[0];
assign mux0[1] = bf_en? bf_x[1] : sr_out[1];

assign mux1[0] = bf_en? bf_y[0] : {rReal[BW-2],rReal};
assign mux1[1] = bf_en? bf_y[1] : {rImag[BW-2],rImag};


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////     Fill your code here    ///////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

endmodule
```

[image: Stage6]
[image: Stage1to5]

My approach was

```
Shift_Reg #(BW,N) sr0(nrst,clk,mux1[0],valid,sr_out[0]);
Shift_Reg #(BW,N) sr1(nrst,clk,mux1[1],valid,sr_out[1]);

BF #(BW)bf0({sr_out[0][BW-1],sr_out[0][BW-3:0]},{sr_out[1][BW-1],sr_out[1][BW-3:0]},rReal,rImag,bf_x[0],bf_x[1],bf_y[0],bf_y[1]);

assign outReal = bf_en? mux0[0] : sr_out[0];
assign outImag = bf_en? mux0[1] : sr_out[1];

always@(posedge clk) begin
    if(!nrst) begin
      rReal <= 0;
      rImag <= 0;
    end
    else if(valid) begin
        
      rReal <= inReal;
      rImag <= inImag;

    end
end
```

The error is occurring due to a "concurrent assignment of a non-net (reg sr_out)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `BF` is driving `sr_out`, then `sr_out` should be defined as a `wire`, not `reg`.

In Verilog, reg variables can  only be assigned inside procedural block (`always`, `initial`, `task`, `function`, etc). Signals driven by assign statements, module instances, and primitives need to be net types (typically `wire`).

SystemVerilog (the superset and successor of Verilog) relaxed this rule. If you are allowed to use SystemVerilog change the file extension from .v to .sv and any modern simulator or synthesizer should be able to correctly parse the code.